# how many iframe tags i could have in one page?

Tags: html, css, browser

Is it possible to have two or more iframes ?

I put two empty "iframe" tags with display:none style.

But i can see only one.

if i'm commenting one in source code, then i can see another one...

```
<iframe id="ab" style="display: none;" />
<iframe id="cd" style="display: none;" />
```

and in inspector (chrome) i can see only one ;(

btw, they are both direct body childs.

Comment: try adding a `src` attribute.

Comment: you can use as many as you want.

Comment: The maximum number is `1,048,576` (actually it's probably `349,524` for iframes).  iframe's aren't self closing tags.  You need `</iframe>`.  Also, you need a src.

Comment: @cwolves Where are you getting your maximum numbers? Practical max is probably significantly lower as well.

Comment: @ceejayoz -- Yes, practical max is ___far___ lower.  It's from a benchmark I ran years ago do determine the maximum number of elements on a page :)  I got a number just below `2^20`, (like 5 below), so `2^20` is the maximum number in whatever browser I tested, minus a few for `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>`, etc.  The `349,524` number comes from my assumed extra `<html>`, `<body>` default nodes for iFrames :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the “self-closing” syntax (`/` before the `>`), use end tags for the `iframe` elements, i.e. `</iframe>`.

Markup like `<iframe id="ab" style="display: none;" />` is in principle conforming in XML, hence in XHTML, and gets interpreted properly by modern browsers when in XHTML mode (for documents served as XHTML). In HTML mode, they see the “self-closing” tags just as start tags, so the result is a mess (and it’s even surprising that *anything* gets displayed).